# Search upwards within script

Tags: scripting

This has boggled my mind for a while now and I've searched everywhere. Whenever I have a long script, I use the [find/replace] tool on the sidebar to search for parts of my code

[image]

However, it only works downwards or so I think. So if I scrolled my script all the way down and have the cursor there to edit a part and want to go back up, I have to scroll all the way up again. place the cursor at the start of the file and run the search again. Surely I must be missing something?

[image]

Comment: You can't search upward as far as I know, but there's the *Wrap* option below which allows looping from the end back to the beginning

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enable wrap option, then it will search in all document

[image]

Comment: GREAT! Sadly, not the same as searching upwards in word documents but definitely a big help. Thank you so much.